# In Sublime Text, how can I increase the difference/contrast of the line highlight color from active file and other open, inactive files?

Tags: sublimetext3, preferences

OSX / Sublime Text 3

In Sublime, I work on several files at a time and have them set up in panes with 2 or more files visible at once. I have my `<key>highlight_line</key>` turned on and configured to be red *(high visibility)* in my current color scheme. Among the three files, the red highlighted line is visible *(and that's good)* but the difference between the active file and the other inactive file(s) is different, but nominal. So, when I return to Sublime from another app, I jump right in and wind up editing the wrong file… often. *(not good)*

I've looked in the default prefs file for a value that appears relevant to what I'm after but to no avail. Any solutions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating another *"help me"* post on [sublime text forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18411&p=68502#p68502), it was suggested that the package ["inactive panes"](https://github.com/SublimeText/InactivePanes) could solve my issue. And it does!! While my ultimate solution to this would be leveraging the application itself in some way, this is a great solution until that becomes possible.